# Background Image Zoomed in Responsive Design (CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

My image: http://path.com.my/v2/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Home-Page-Banner-B.jpg
Website: http://path.com.my/v2/
**Check 2nd slide**

The slider image, no matter what resolution of images I put in, it will still 'zooming' in too much in the center and cut off too much details. Changing the the image aspect ratio doesn't seem to do any good either.

I have try to use background-size: cover, but it would leave blank spaces on the side, and doesn't do any good in different screen sizes too.

Any idea on how to best achieve this so I can put in my image with the least crop or zoom in?

Comment: I don't see a slider on your webpage and this design is the opposite from being responsive.

Comment: @Frutis sorry, re-edit the link, it should be http://path.com.my/v2

Comment: After putting this image, either you can give the image height:300px or if fullwidth is needed then add width:100%;height:300px;object-fit:cover; for img style

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.home #content .slide {
    /*[...]*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 87%;
    background-position: 250px 0;
}
```

Comment: That works fine for desktop and laptop but it leaves a big white space in mobile view, i define media at min width for 1280px for this, is it better with this width or?